# How to conditionally bind TextCell Detail attribute?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

In a xamarin.forms android project I am working on, I have a list of objects that I want to display in a ListView. The objects are based on ClassA:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ClassB> Types { get; set; }
}
```

Note the List of ClassB objects. ClassB looks like this:

```
public class ClassB
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

I have this partially working using XAML, like this:

```
<TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Types[0].Count }" Tapped="Cell_OnTapped" />
```

The issue is that the binding for the Detail attribute needs to change for each row depending on the value of the ClassA.ClassB.Type property. E.g. if `Types[0].Count > 0` then the TextCell binding for the Detail attribute should be:

```
Types[0].Count
```

If `Types[0].Count > 0` AND `Types[1].Count > 0` then the TextCell binding for the Detail attribute should be:

```
"type 1 count: " + Types[0].Count + "type 2: count: " Types[1].Count
```

Note that there are never more than three items in ClassA.Types. Also, ClassB.Count values are all precalculated.

What would be the best way to go about this using xamarin.forms for Android?

Comment: you can create a read-only Property and bind to it, and put the logic for the conditional with the property

Comment: I think you should be able to use a ValueConverter and pass in Type and then return your string

Comment: Best way is to pass the BindingContext to the value converter and get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a value converter, like so (note: untested code!):

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter, IMarkupExtension
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (Equals(value,null))
                return string.Empty;

            var obj = (ClassA)value;

            // Your logic here to work out the string to display
            // NOTE: untested - may need to add null checks, etc.
            if (obj.Types[0].Count > 0 && obj.Types[1].Count > 0) 
            {
                return "type 1 count: " + Types[0].Count + "type 2: count: " Types[1].Count;
            }
            else if (obj.Types[0].Count > 0)
            {
                return Types[0].Count;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Only one way bindings are supported with this converter");
        }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

And then in your XAML, bind like so:

```
<TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding ., Converter={converters:MyConverter} }" Tapped="Cell_OnTapped" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that result by two different approaches.

1: ValueConverter.

You bind directly you `Types` property from ClassA and do the logic of what to display inside the ValueConverter. More about this [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/).

2: ViewModel

Implement a ViewModel that will be composed from you `ClassA` object.

Taking your models

```
public class ClassA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ClassB> Types { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

and your requirements, you can implement a ViewModel like the one bellow:

```
public class ItemViewModel()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public ItemViewModel(ClassA classA)
    {
        Name = classA.Name;

        if( classA.Types[0].Count > 0 )
        {
            Type = $"{classA.Types[0].Count}";
        }
        else if (classA.Types[0].Count > 0 && classA.Types[1].Count > 0)
        {
            Type = $"type 1 count: {Types[0].Count} type 2: count: {Types[1].Count}";
        }
    }
}
```

And using Linq you can convert your List items to a new list of your ViewModel items.

```
List<ClassA> Items = ......

var ItemVm = Items.Select(a => New ItemViewModel(a)).ToList();
```

Use the ItemVm to bind it to your View.

Hope this helps.-

Note: I didn't do any validation for the Types List to be null but I encourage you to do it.

Note 2: You might also need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel.